# CollectionView inside another CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

I am trying to create `collectionView` inside another `collectionViewCell`. I can get the cell of outer `collectionView` however, compiler is not executing inner cell. How can I get both the cells?

P.S I am new at this.

**CollectionViewController Class:**

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

@IBOutlet var collectionView1: UICollectionView!

var coll2 = CollectionViewCell()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 150)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    return cell

}

}
```

**CollectionViewCell CLass:**

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell  {

@IBOutlet var collectionView2: UICollectionView!

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView2.frame.width, height: 150)
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)as! CollectionViewCell2

    cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return cell1

 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoGn7.png)
}

Answer (score 1):

set the delegates and data source of inner collection view to the first collection view cell.

```
override func awakeFromNib() 
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    self.collectionView2?.delegate = self
    self.collectionView2?.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: I have tried putting this in CollectionViewCell (outer cell) but getting error:   unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: try 
      self.collectionView2?.delegate = self
     self.collectionView2?.dataSource = self

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `CollectionViewCell` is not setting up the `collectionView2` is because you didn't set `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of `collectionView2` to the instance of `CollectionViewCell`.

I have created a method called `setupViews` in `CollectionViewCell` so that it can be called when you are dequeuing a `CollectionViewCell` in `CollectionViewController` so that the delegate and dataSource are being setup properly.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
  }


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 150)
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    cell.setupViews() // added this call

    return cell
  }

}
```

---

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!

  // added this method
  func setupViews() {
    collectionView2.delegate = self
    collectionView2.dataSource = self
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView2.frame.width, height: 150)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) 

    cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return cell1

  }

}
```